# gtk_window_set_transient_for: assertion 'parent == null". Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3

I'm using GTK and I get this error saying Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged. I am using a gtk dialog on top of a GtkWindow. I saw in other posts that you can use the gtk_window_set_transient_for but I don't know I'm using it correctly.

```
GtkWidget* dialog;
GtkWidget* window;
gtk_widget_set_transient_for((GtkWindow*)dialog, (GtkWindow*)window)
```

However, I am still getting the same error. How do I fix it?

Comment: Please add a minimal and reproducible example to help us see the problem.

Comment: I've had the same problem and fixed it by passing `parent` during construction.